# Django download file button takes in path

Tags: python, django

I am creating an app that allows users to convert their .ifc (3D model) files into other data forms (.xlsx, filtered .xlsx, json). I have managed to implement the upload part, but now I am not sure about the download.

I would like to create a "download" button that takes in the users desired download path (maybe even file name). When I have the path I can start my conversion function with the last uploaded file.

```
def model_form_download(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        download_path = ??? #How to take in the user defined upload path?
        
        last_model = Document.objects.latest("uploaded_at") 
        last_model_name = last_model.document.name
        
        MODEL_DIR = Path(MEDIA_DIR) / last_model_name       
        model = parser(MODEL_DIR)                           

        xlsx_name = Path(last_model_name).stem                                
        
        XLS_DIR = Path(download_path) / (xlsx_name + '.xlsx')  
       
        model[1].to_excel(XLS_DIR)                          
        
        return render(request, 'core/model_form_download.html')
    return render(request, 'core/model_form_download.html')
```

The extra question here is how to take in the user choice of prefered conversion format and use in this view function?

Answer (score 0):

```
def model_form_download(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        download_path = ??? #How to take in the user defined upload path?
        
        last_model = Document.objects.latest("uploaded_at") 
        last_model_name = last_model.document.name
        
        MODEL_DIR = Path(MEDIA_DIR) / last_model_name       
        model = parser(MODEL_DIR)                           

        xlsx_name = Path(last_model_name).stem                                
        
        XLS_DIR = Path(download_path) / (xlsx_name + '.xlsx')  
       
        model[1].to_excel(XLS_DIR)                          
        
        return render(request, 'core/model_form_download.html')
    return render(request, 'core/model_form_download.html')
```

How to take in the user defined upload path?

if you have a form on the frontend like this:

```
<form>
<input name="download_path" .../>
...
```

Then in you django view you can access it from request

```
download_path = request.POST.get("download_path")
```

the same goes for the conversion format, just add it to a form and access it from the request object.

although really you should consider using forms: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/